# using Zbar library in Android project

Tags: android-ndk, zbar

I am developping an Android App in witch I want to use Zbar library functions to facilitate Qr code Scan. I am using Android SDK+NDK. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/zbar-bar-code-qr-code-reader-android/). It worked pretty well until the last step, i don't manage to build NDK.

The error I have is :

```
fatal error: com_hae_zapp_Zbar.h: No file or directory.
```

I looked for this file but it seems unfound. Does anybody know how would I overcome that problem? Do they use Zbar SDK? ( I use the standard android SDK )

Answer (score 2):

I`m not sure if this is the kind of answer that you are expecting, but if you are having problems trying to integrate ZBar with your application, you should try to use the [DushyanthMaguluru / ZBarScanner library](https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner) to simplify the use.

I have used this library in my application and took me about 20 minutes to be able to use the qrcode scanner.